# Prompt file download

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, reactjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have a link on my page on click of which I am trying to generate a PDF document and then show the "Open - Save" prompt on the browser.

My HTML (reactjs component) has the below code where `onclick` calls the `_getMyDocument` function which then calls a Webapi method.

```
 <div className="row">
     <a href="#" onClick={this._getMyDocument.bind(this)}>Test Link</a>
 </div>  

_getMyDocument(e) {
            GetMyDocument(this.props.mydata).then(()=> {
   }).catch(error=> {

  });
```

My Controller has the below code

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Generate/Report")]
public IHttpActionResult GetMyReport(MyData myData)
 {  
    byte[] myDoc = MyBusinessObject.GenerateMyReport(myData);
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(myDoc)
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
            new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "MyDocument.pdf"
            };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        var response = ResponseMessage(result);

        return response;
  }
```

Currently all the code executes but I don't get the file PDF download prompt. What am I doing wrong here?

Response object on success from the ajax call lokks like below

[image]

Comment: Did you try my solution. Please give your feedback.

Comment: I tried assigning the download URL following @Ermir Beqiraj's answer.  var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' }); var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);  window.location = fileURL; This is downloading a PDF but an invalid one.

Comment: what is `MyBusinessObject.GenerateMyReport(myData);` doing?.. is it making a request to another application?

Comment: It makes a call to another library (inhouse) which uses Microsoft Report viewer to generate the report data (btye array).

Answer (score 10):

Your response from the server looks good. 
The missing part is that you are not handling this response from the client side in the correct way.

Lets assume that your resource url object looks like below in js. (i.e. you already know the resource url, if you don't know it yet, then you will need a separate call to the server to know the download url)

```
response.downloadUrl = app/media/fileId/document.pdf
```

All you need to do is set,

```
window.location = item.downloadUrl;
```

This will cause the browser to request a resource from the server, the response from the server **must** include `Content-Disposition:attachment;`. It will cause the browser to show the download dialog.

P.S. I have recently worked on a similar functionality. If you have questions please ask.

When you want to force the browser to show the download prompt for some files (or resources), you must include  `Content-Disposition:attachment;` in the response header (which you already did).

Comment: I am using Microsoft report viewer to generate the pdf. There is no actual file present to set the download url. I have updated my question to include the response object.

Comment: @San, by download url I mean any web service address (server request) which will return you pdf in response. So if call to Microsoft report viewer returns you the pdf, you need to assign the same call request to variable  `window.location`

Comment: I have assigned the URL by doing - >var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' }); var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)

Answer (score 2):

In our app(angular) we had to create an object url for that with a code like:

WebApi:

```
result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(data);
result.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                        new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                        {
                            FileName = "FileNameHere"
                        };

return result;
```

javascript:

```
// HttpCall in here
// On SuccessResponse
    var file = new Blob([data], {
                    type: 'application/pdf'
                    });
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
// create an anchor and click on it.
    var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
    anchorTag.href = fileURL;
    anchorTag.target = '_blank';
    anchorTag.download = 'CouponOrder.pdf';
    document.body.appendChild(anchorTag);
    anchorTag.click();
    document.body.removeChild(anchorTag);
```

Comment: This downloads the file. But shows as damaged file when tried to open.

Comment: @San, open the resulting file in notepad and see if your getting content that is not a pdf document.. namely a 500 error or some exception message from your call to `MyBusinessObject.GenerateMyReport`

Comment: There is no exception. I have verfied the size of data returned by MyBusinessObject.GenerateMyReport and have also written it to a pdf file directly.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this is on your server to use GET method, and receive your data by query parameters.

Then in your client app you just have to create a classic link:

```
<a href="http://your-server.com/your-resource?param1=123&param2=456">Test Link</a>
```

Or use that simple js script if your want to manage it from your script logic:

```
window.open("http://your-server.com/your-resource?param1=123&param2=456");
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Content Disposition and add it to your response header

```
var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    // for example foo.bak
    FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName),
    // always prompt the user for downloading, set to true if you want 
    // the browser to try to show the file inline
    Inline = false,
};
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the GetMyDocument function will receive the PDF file as a server response, and currently you are doing nothing with that response.  You need to handle the response in the then callback.  Saving files from javascript is not entirely simple, so I would recommend using an external library such as [filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to help you.

It will end up looking something like...

```
_getMyDocument(e) {
    GetMyDocument(this.props.mydata)
    .then((response)=> {
        const returnedFile = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf'});
        saveAs(returnedFile);
    }).catch(error=> {

    });
```

Comment: Trying to use Filesaver.js how do I read the data fromt he response?. new File() expects two arguments and expects data be array.

Comment: Looked into this a bit more and I think we will need to use blob rather than file - I have edited.

Comment: var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });           FileSaver.saveAs(file); This generates blank document. Does this require any conversion before passing to Blob?

Comment: What about if you use new Blob([response.data]) ?

Comment: It also downloads. but instead of blank page it gives invalid pdf data error on file open.

Comment: @AlexYoung : Well, we don't necessarily need an external library. We can do it in pure js as well. Please see my answer.

Comment: @San, same consideration as the comment I left on the other answer. open the resulting file in notepad and see if your getting content that is not a pdf document.. namely a 500 error or some exception message from your call to `MyBusinessObject.GenerateMyReport`

Comment: Opening the downloaded document in textpad shows up text "[object Object]". I have verified the data by writing myDoc to pdf file from the controller and it writes the data successfully. If the way I am sending the response is right I believe the problem lies in the way I am reading the response in javascript -> var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' }.