# How to download file using post in js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonna download file using javascript or jquery.
I have to send request using post, cause I am sending also some data for file generation.

Currently I have:

```
$.ajax(reportGenerateUrl + reportName,{
                    contentType : "application/pdf",
                    processData : false,
                    method : "POST",
                    headers : csrfHeaders(),
                    data: criteria,
                    success : function(data, status, jqHXR) {
                        alert('Report generated!');

                    },
                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data) {
                        alert('Unable to get report!');

                    }
                });
```

My server returns pdf file, but no download prompt. I am getting file ooutput in network page in chrome dev tools.

Can any one help?

Comment: you can create HTML hidden form through java script and then use `form.submit()` on it

Comment: @Arvind this is not true. You just have to handle the disposition yourself. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23797348/4108884

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prompt file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662885/prompt-file-download)