# How to send a file from Django backend to server

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am sending an ajax request with a file to my backend that processes it. After processing it into another form (image into a compressed processed directory), I want to send that back to the user to down load that. Can someone provide an example view that will, when it receives the file, process the data the send a request that has the file. Also, please show me how to download that file in the javascript front end.

```
class send_text:
    def post(self, request):
        file = request.POST["file"]
        # Processing…………… file_to_send = <path to file>
        # show how to send the file here
```

Also the frond end:

```
$.ajax{
//sending the data
onSuccess: //show how to download the data here
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662885/prompt-file-download for the download part to run in onSuccess and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156246/having-django-serve-downloadable-files for the serving the downloadable content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else, I have figured this out by using static files. Please use the  tag with the download option. For an example:

`<a href="{%get_static_prefix%}{{file_name}}/{{file_name}}.pdf" id="printer" download='{{file_name}}.pdf'></a>`

Please note that if you wanna automatically download the file for the user, you make a function. Inside the function type this:

`document.getElementById("<<name of <a> tag, here: printer>>").click()`